# How to perform power analysis for repeated measures with observation error?

Tags: repeated-measures, statistical-power, measurement-error

I am interested in producing two raster maps of the same areas but separated in time. I would like to take the average value of all pixels in each map and test if there is a difference in that mean between the earlier and later map. Each pixel has an observation (aka measurement) error of, say, 3 meters. I would like to see what sample size (number of pixels) I would need to detect a difference (given $\alpha = 0.05$) of 0.01 meters.

I have read up on power analyses, but I can't find anything addressing repeated measures with observation error. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: http://rpubs.com/bbolker/11703

Comment: Thanks Ben.  So, best way is to simulate?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, since you have only two samples (before vs after) I think you can consider this as a paired $t$ test: you're trying to detect a difference in the average value of (after-before).  There are many canned power calculators for this case, including `power.t.test()` in R:

```
power.t.test(delta=0.01,sd=3*sqrt(2),power=0.8,type="paired")

     Paired t test power calculation 

              n = 1412800
          delta = 0.01
             sd = 4.242641
      sig.level = 0.05
          power = 0.8
    alternative = two.sided

NOTE: n is number of *pairs*, sd is std.dev. of *differences* within pairs
```

I have increased the sd to $3\sqrt{2}$ because (as noted in the output) we want the standard deviation of differences.  I hope 1.5 million pixels is not a depressing answer ...

If we assume that the standard deviation *between pairs of measurements on the same pixel* is the same as the standard deviation *across pixels at the same time*, then the paired $t$ test doesn't give you any advantage over the pooled test (`power.t.test(delta=0.01,sd=3,power=0.8,type="two.sample")` gives exactly the same answer).  However, if the measurement error is what you say, and there is some true among-pixel variation, then the standard deviation in the two-sample test will be even larger, and the results will be even worse (but the paired test will not lose any power).